# why does updating a real table from a self-join temp table is not working but when using a real table it works?

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

Here's the scenario:

Procedure 1 creates temp table #t.

Procedure 1 executes procedure 2.

Procedure 2 populates #t.

In procedure 1, I insert into a real table from #t just so I can view the data.
The data is there.

Immediately after viewing this data, I do an update with a self-join. Like so:

```
  update b
  set b.column1 = a.column3
  from #t a
    inner join #t b on a.id = b.id;
```

The record that is supposed to be updated IS NOT UPDATING.

However, if I change #t to a real table "dbo.t" and do exactly the same thing, it works.

I'm so confused. Anyone has any idea why this could be? Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the SQL in its entirety. I am guessing it's a scope thing (Local vs Global). If they truly are separate procedures, as you've indicated in your example, then it is a scope thing. Check out this article: http://www.itprotoday.com/software-development/temporary-tables-local-vs-global

Comment: No one can read your mind, see you actual code, or look at your database. Nor does anyone know the keys (primary, unique) to your temp table. Is ID unique? If you "think" it is, do you know this or do you assume this? Is that enforced in your table DDL? If the id column is not unique, then that means a given row can join to multiple rows and the value of column3 used to update column1 can come from any of these joined rows.

Comment: I created a simple example with all the information you gave and the `UPDATE` works fine, so it would seem there's something going on behind the scenes somewhere. Can you post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Also, what exactly is that join supposed to accomplish? Perhaps there's something I'm not seeing since you haven't shared any details about what that table looks like or what it contains, but it seems to me that the `UPDATE` would work just as well without the join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the MS SQL Docs:

> A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped
>   automatically when the stored procedure is finished. The table can be
>   referenced by any nested stored procedures executed by the stored
>   procedure that created the table. The table cannot be referenced by
>   the process that called the stored procedure that created the table.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I think this might be the problem. im modifying my procedure so that the child procedure doesn't need to be used to populate #t and see if it works.

Comment: @RJ this is one time maybe a staging table would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks all. The issue was that I needed to create a global variable. There were 3 procedures involved. The outer most executed the inner one multiple times and then this inner one executed the last one several times. I had to create this global variable in the inner one and make sure it wasn't being created if it already existed.